# EF6 Silent Error. How can I get more detail on why I'm failing on context.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm baffled on this one.
 Nothing returns from context.SaveChanges() it never goes to the catch it never finishes and the variable r never gets assigned a value.

How can I find out what the error is?

```
public void DeleteStuff(int stuffID)
{ 
    using (var context = new MYConn())
    {
        var user = new MY_STUFF { STUFF_ID = stuffID};
        var entry = context.Entry(user);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            context.MY_STUFF.Attach(user);
        }
        context.MY_STUFF.Remove(user);
        try
        {
            var r = context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `InnerException` property usually contains more useful exceptions when working with EF

Comment: It doesn't go to the catch statement.  I only added that line to set a break point.

Comment: "It never finishes": How long did you wait?

Comment: Have you tried putting a SQL sniffer to see what he is doing behind the scenes? Perhaps it is deadlocking

Comment: Thanks Octanic! Oracle SQL Developer had an uncommitted transaction on that record I was trying to delete with EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Octanic suggested, after I put a sniffer on I realized I had a deadlock.